# iOS App Store receipt file does not exist

Tags: ios, receipt

I try to read the App Store receipt (iOS7) in the sandbox/development environment. I make a SKReceiptRefreshRequest, if the file does not exist (which is always). It always calls request:didFailWithError: on my delegate. Why is that? I thought Apple will provide fake receipts while developing for testing?

Comment: Code 0. The operation couldn't be completed.

Comment: I am not positive, but I believe you need to have the app setup in itunesconnect.apple.com. Even though it hasn't been "published".   This is a little bit more than just creating an app id.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, it is already in the store

Comment: The receipt is still signed by apple and although is "fake", it still comes from the apple server as far as I know.  A couple of questions.  Are you running the app on a device or in a simulator?  If on a real device, does the device have network connectivity?  3) Are you deleting the app and installing new every time you run it?  I have seen it take a few seconds before the receipt appears the first time the app is run if previous versions were deleted.  And I believe in one of the documents I read said you need to be able to handle the case were the receipt is initially not present.

Comment: Device and simulator (same errors). My devices have network connectivity. I don't always delete it every time I'm running it.

Comment: how did you manage to make SKReceiptRefreshRequest work? According to Apple now the receipt is unified for iOS and OSX, so probably also the verification. Every time I try to use it on cocoa I get a message telling me the app is corrupt and that I should download it again from the app store.

Comment: See the answer to my own question. My problem was I was not logged in as a test user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reminder for myself and others facing stupid problems like this: Log in with a test user account!

Everything works now. Thanks guys